# Split two words connected by a dot

Tags: r, regex, string, strsplit

I have a big dataframe with news articles. I have noticed that some of the articles have two words connected by a dot as the following examples shows `The government.said it was important to quit.`. I will conduct some topic modelling, so I need to separate every single word.

**This is the code I have used to separate those words**

```
    #String example
    test <- c("i need.to separate the words connected by dots. however, I need.to keep having the dots separating sentences")

    #Code to separate the words
    test <- do.call(paste, as.list(strsplit(test, "\\.")[[1]]))

   #This is what I get
  > test
  [1] "i need to separate the words connected by dots  however, I need to keep having the dots separating sentences"
```

As you can see, I deleted all the dots (periods) on the text. How could I get the following outcome:

```
"i need to separate the words connected by dots. however, I need to keep having the dots separating sentences"
```

**Final note**

My dataframe is composed of 17.000 articles; all the text is on lowercase. I just provided a small example of the issue I am having when trying to separate two words connected by a dot. Additionally, is there any way I can use `strsplit` on a list?

Comment: Try `gsub("\\b\\.\\b", " ", test, perl=TRUE)`. This will remove dots in between letters/digits/underscores. If it is not exactly what you need, could you explain in detail the context where you want to remove the dots?

Comment: It works. Is there any chance I can apply this code without modifying urls? My dataframe consists of different news articles that have some urls within them. I would like to keep them but this code would definitely alter them.

Comment: Please provide an example and update the question.

Comment: I will post a new one as you have correctly answered this one for me. Thanks!

Comment: No, please don't, I will post an answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
test <- c("i need.to separate the words connected by dots. however, I need.to keep having the dots separating sentences. Look at http://google.com for s.0.m.e more details.")
# Replace each dot that is in between word characters
gsub("\\b\\.\\b", " ", test, perl=TRUE)
# Replace each dot that is in between letters
gsub("(?<=\\p{L})\\.(?=\\p{L})", " ", test, perl=TRUE)
# Replace each dot that is in between word characters, but no in URLs
gsub("(?:ht|f)tps?://\\S*(*SKIP)(*F)|\\b\\.\\b", " ", test, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/SkcVQ2).

Output:

```
[1] "i need to separate the words connected by dots. however, I need to keep having the dots separating sentences. Look at http://google com for s 0 m e more details."
[1] "i need to separate the words connected by dots. however, I need to keep having the dots separating sentences. Look at http://google com for s.0.m e more details."
[1] "i need to separate the words connected by dots. however, I need to keep having the dots separating sentences. Look at http://google.com for s 0 m e more details."
```

**Details**

- `\b\.\b` - a dot that is enclosed with word boundaries (i.e. before and after `.` cannot be any non-word char, there cannot be any char other than a letter, digit or underscore
- `(?<=\p{L})\.(?=\p{L})` matches a dot that is not immediately preceded nor followed with a letter (`(?<=\p{L})` is a negative lookbehind and the `(?=\p{L})` is a negative lookahead)
- `(?:ht|f)tps?://\\S*(*SKIP)(*F)|\b\.\b` matches `http/ftp` or `https/ftps`, then `://` and then any 0 or more non-whitespace chars, and skips the match and goes on to search for matches from the position it was when it came across the SKIP PCRE verb.